# MacRuby release app missing libmacruby.dylib

Tags: xcode, macruby

Using XCode 4.5.2 and MacRuby 0.12, my app works fine on my computer but the release version won't work on others computers :

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/MacRuby.framework/Versions/0.12/usr/lib/libmacruby.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/PocheFactory.app/Contents/MacOS/PocheFactory
  Reason: image not found
```

I have checked my deployment settings and they seems fine:
In the BuildPhases->"Link Binary With Libraries", I have the "MacRuby.framework" required and in the BuildSettings->Framework Search Paths, I have include "/Library/Frameworks" with recursive option.

How come this particular library is not included within the release version?
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than figuring out the right Xcode settings, it's *much* easier to run this:

/usr/local/bin/macruby_deploy --compile --embed

I got this info from Matt Aimonetti's *MacRuby, The Definitive Guide*.

(The last command argument was stripped off: it's the path to the application bundle in Derived Data that was created by Xcode.)